# t-value two-sided confidence interval BIBD

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Consider a BIBD in b = 20 blocks of size k = 2 units each for comparing t = 5 treatments.

What t-value would be used to construct a $95\%$ two-sided confidence interval for $\tau_1-\tau_2$?
How can i calculate this any ideas?

Comment: BIBD  is presumably *balanced incomplete block design*.  You say $t=5$ treatments. Do you mean $t$-value or $t$-design?

Comment: i mean t-value.